# Does anyone know how to get this to work i am trying to use pagecontrol to make a slideshow but index shows a error

Tags: swift, uipagecontrol

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var images: [String] = ["0","1","2"]
var frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    pageControl.numberOfPages = images.count
    for idex in 0..<images.count {
        frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width
            * CGFloat(index)
        // the code above me shows a error
        frame.size = scrollView.frame.size
        let imgView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        imgView.image = UIImage(named: images[index])
```

this code above as well

self.scrollView.addSubview(imgView)
        }
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:(scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(images.count)), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the actual loop by this loop :

```
for index in 0..<images.count {
   ...
```